# Is working with cardboard that are used for beer storage Haram to work with

Tags: halal-haram, work

I'm forklift operator and I recently got this job that deals with cardboards and graphics cards, my job is to move pallets of this cardboard/ graphics cards around the warehouse and load them into trucks, some of the cardboards are used for beer storage and they have the different brands of beer labeled in each pallet of cardboard , I know working with cardboard on itself is halal but is working with cardboard you know that will be used for beer storage Haram? Jazakallah.